# Question on states and nets in a non-unital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, nets

Let $A$ be a non-unital $C^*$ algebra, and let $a_\lambda$ be a net such that $a_\lambda b \to 0$ for all $b \in A$. Show that for any state $f, f(a_\lambda) \to 0$.

I tried using approximate units, but to no avail...

Comment: Where is this exercise from?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer using machinery: By the Cohen-Factorisation theorem, any functional $f\in A^*$ is of the form $f = \omega(-b)$ for some $b \in A$ and $\omega \in A^*$. Then
$$f(a_\lambda) = \omega(a_\lambda b) \to \omega(0) = 0.$$

---

If the net $\{a_\lambda\}$ is bounded, you can proceed as follows.

Let $(H_f, \pi_f, \xi_f)$ be the GNS-triplet associated with $f$. We claim that $\pi_f(a_\lambda) \to 0$ in the strong topology on $B(H_f)$. Indeed, since the net $\{\pi_f(a_\lambda)\}$ is bounded, it suffices to check the strong convergence on the dense subspace $\pi_f(A)\xi_f$. But
$$\pi_f(a_\lambda)\pi_f(b) \xi_f = \pi_f(a_\lambda b)\xi_f \to 0$$
since $a_\lambda b \to 0$ so this is clear. It thus follows that
$$f(a_\lambda) = \langle \pi_f(a_\lambda)\xi_f, \xi_f\rangle\to 0$$
since $\pi_f(a_\lambda)\xi_f \to 0$.

Comment: Do you know of an answer that doesn't use this?

Comment: @steedsnisps I know one if the net is bounded.

Comment: Okay, feel free to share

Comment: @steedsnisps I just did. There is probably an elementary answer for the general (unbounded) case, but I don't see it immediately.